# "The opposite / opposites of these words"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I am rather confused as to what to say:

> **The opposite** of these words.

or,

> **The opposites** of these words.

When I think that as **we are talking about one opposite for each word** we should use the former one **but** in contrast, I sometimes think that **when "words" is plural we should use "opposites" and not "opposite".**

How grammar explains this?

Comment: Using singular "opposite" would mean that you want to find one opposite of multiple words.  Plural "opposites" means that you want to find multiple opposites for these words.  Try replacing "opposite" with "antonym".  "The antonym of these words" vs "The antonyms of these words".  Looking for one antonym vs multiple.

Comment: It's no different to asking *Who is the **mother** of these children?* as opposed to *Who are the **mothers** of these children?* (The ***children*** are always plural, regardless of how many mothers there might be.) Are you expecting the answer to be a ***singular*** noun, or some kind of ***plural*** reference (reflected by whether  you refer to ***opposite*** or ***opposites***).